# Centering three.js renderer.domElement (canvas) inside a parent div

Tags: css, three.js

I'm having difficulty understanding how to 'style' the output of a threejs renderer within an html div.

For instance here is a simple scene:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/craigjwallace/ehvu0ph3/)

html:

```
<div id="myPlanet"></div>
```

css:

```
body {
background : #000;
padding : 50px;
margin : 0;
}
#myPlanet {
width : 400px;
min-height: 400px;
margin : auto;
}
```

and an excerpt of the js:

```
// The WIDTH of the scene to render
var __WIDTH__  = 400,

// The HEIGHT ot the scene to render
__HEIGHT__ = 400,
// We need to define the size of the renderer
renderer.setSize(__WIDTH__, __HEIGHT__);

// Let's attach our rendering zone to our page
document.getElementById("myPlanet").appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

The output is exactly centered, in the resulting page, if the element width (in css) exactly matches the renderer width. But when the div 'myplanet' is extended (width) beyond the 400px of the renderer, (i.e. changing the css rules to 600px width or 100%) the jsthree output then just sits on the left of the element.

How can this be centered? In css must you create a special rule case (eg like #myplanet img or something) which you can then style?  I have tried putting 'margin : 0 auto;' in the myplanet rules but it still won't center the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<canvas>` element is treated by default as an inline object, similar to the `<img>` element. This makes it posibble to mix text and images by using `float:left;` or `float:right;` properties. I have added some text inside the parent div and a transparent red background in order to exhibit this behavior.

[image: inline canvas]

In this scenario you have two options.

**1) Set `margin: auto` for canvas element**
Also specify that the canvas should be treated by the browser's page rendering engine as a block element.

```
#canvas{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You get this:

[image: disaply:block, margin:auto]

**2)Set `text-align: center` for the parent div**

Optionally, you can specify the vertical alignment property of the inline elements.

```
#myPlanet{
    text-align: center;
   /* vertical-align: middle; */
}
```

I highly recommend the first option.

[image: text-align:center]

Comment: Brilliant - thanks Adrian. Canvas element works great.